# Get VBA to recognize different Japanese writing systems

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to get Excel VBA to recognize different Japanese writing systems?

For example, say I wanted to perform a StrConv function with a Japanese sentence as my string, is there a way to separate out the hiragana/katakana/kanji and just do the StrConv on one writing system or the other?

Comment: Compare The return values of `AscW()` with the ranges given here: http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml ?

Comment: Awesome, that sounds like it'll work! I'd have to split the string into an array characters and compare each of them in a loop right? (Sorry, total newbie at this).

Comment: `Mid(s,i,1)` is the character in string `s` at index `i` (where the indexing is 1-based). I haven't used Unicode and VBA much at all and have the impression that VBA's Unicode handling is somewhat problematic. More recent versions of Excel have a worksheet function called `Unicode`. If you have such a version you could call this function from VBA: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/UNICODE-function-adb74aaa-a2a5-4dde-aff6-966e4e81f16f

Comment: My main struggle is with Unicode encoding, but luckily I do think I have a version with `Unicode` so I'll look into it. Thank you very much!